# Drag and drop items to build a diagram

Tags: c#, java, opengl, drag-and-drop, diagram

We are software engineering students that were asked to do a project to help the chemistry department voluntarily outside of classes.

We are trying to build a program to build chemistry labatory diagrams. The main idea would be to have a series of items, being the many components in a labatory (like decanters for example), that could be dragged and dropped onto a canvas. Once on the canvas, they can be deleted, resized or moved. Some of the components are used as link between the other components, have would have to recognize which items are at each end or this connector to validate if the connection is possible. A little like some UML applications do.

We are only in the conception process at this point, but were wondering how to do something like this. I know Java and C# .net, but never did this kind of projet before. I saw a little of OpenGL with C++, but I only created simple forms on a canvas...

If you have suggestions on functions I have to look at or can point me to some kind of tutorial, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we can't answer a quesion like this on here and you didn't mentionate if you are talking about winform or webform. In both of these cases there are lots of example on internet on how do drap and drop in both the context.Regarding the "business login" you have to write it yourself

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "business login". Maybe because english is not my main language... It's for winforms. I found exemples for drag and drops, I even did some in openGL with shapes created on a grid, but dragging not from outside the grid onto it. And even so, the item would be represented by an icon, which when dragged onto the canvas it would become a shape different from the icon dragged. (a little like a paint program)

Comment: I think @Massimiliano meant "business logic".

Comment: @Liviu: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812) but, Richard, please follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), including stating specific restrictions, what you've tried so far, and what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding advanced GUI features like drag-n-drop, these are very difficult to implement using raw OpenGL ("[endless nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78238/opengl-user-interface-programming)"). You might look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78238/opengl-user-interface-programming).

Comment: Thank you for this. That's in part what I wanted to know : if it was possible to do it that way.

Right now, I am trying to build a prototype in C# .net WinForms. I'll see if it possible to do it that way.